# Eclipse PHP IDE - custom auto complete tags

Tags: php, eclipse, autocomplete

New to Eclipse IDE and was wondering is there is a way of adding an auto complete/change so that if I type:

```
mres
```

it will translate it to

```
mysql_real_escape_string()
```

I know of the normal PHP code completion, but couldn't see anything about making custom shortcuts.

Thanks,
Niggles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you using PDT, create your own PHP Template. From the menu Window > Preferences, choose PHP > Editor > Templates. Click New button, then use `mres` as the template name, then put

```
mysql_real_escape_string(${cursor})
```

as a pattern.

To use it, just type mres and press Ctrl+Space. If there are no other alternative for the `mres`, then your template will be used right away. If you happened to have 2 or more templates that started with `mres` or contain `mres` in the template name, a popup will be showed so you can choose which you want to use.

Answer (score -2):

Well, I don't know about the IDE but why not type mres and when you're done with the code, you can replace all occurrances with "mysql_real_escape_string".

Another way is to create a function like this:

```
 function mres($string)
 {
 return mysql_real_escape_string($string);
 }
```

Comment: The danger in that is code that may be confusing if someone else took it over - if it's a real PHP function I prefer to leave it as is.

Comment: yup, useless encapsulation that serve no specific purpose.