# Eclipse PHP IDE

Tags: eclipse, ide, eclipse-plugin

> **Similar title but different question to**
>        [Eclipse PHP IDE - custom auto complete tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130023/eclipse-php-ide-custom-auto-complete-tags)

> **Possible duplicate of**
>        [Getting started with PHP in Eclipse IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020519/getting-started-with-php-in-eclipse-ide)

Doe's anyone know a tool / IDE / plugin in Eclipse for PHP development?

I already try the [ZEND PDT](http://www.zend.com/en/community/pdt) but it seems that it has a bug and it doesn't install in my eclipse. I even follow [this workaround in installing it](http://recursivecall.com/2011/coding/projects/installing-eclipse-for-php-troubleshooting-zend-and-pdt) but it still doesn't work.

My Eclipse verions is 4.1.2, OS is in Windows XP SP3.

The previous questions doesn't seems to have a solid answer. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you specifically asked for an Eclipse plugin, but let me take the liberty of recommending a non-Eclipse PHP IDE, because it's really good and deserves a mention here: [PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) from JetBrains.

If you're very keen on Eclipse, [Aptana Studio](http://aptana.com/) is a good IDE based on the Eclipse code base.

Comment: I do not have the luxury to purchase such _exorbitant software_. I'll just look at Aptana, thanks.

Comment: I agree with you that JetBrains products like PhpStorm, WebStorm & ReSharper deserve to be mentioned as excellent IDEs & developer tools, and worth their cost :) too bad they're not opensource

Answer (score 4):

Another very good IDE to devolpe in PHP is NetBeans:

http://netbeans.org/

Answer (score 1):

Pardon a possibly dumb question, but why are you using Eclipse 4.1.2? I suspect that the problem is with a bug in the 3.x compatibility layer in that version.

Unless you have a real need to be using 4.1.2 (and since it was a beta, I'm not sure what that would be...), perhaps try again with 3.7.2, which is the version currently listed on the Eclipse download page[1].

Hope that helps!

[1] http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/